# Implementation of Zoom at a certain area in unity 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Is there any way to implement a zooming concept in collaboration with UI images in unity 2D. Any suggestions and answers are welcome.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use another camera to zoom area....

Answer (score 0):

You can use another camera an duel with it. For example:

http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/PiotrSobolewski/20160512/272600/Implementing_a_minimap_in_Unity_tutorial.php

Comment: Thnaks for your response. I already did by using that tutorial for a 3d game but for 2d its nor working. Render texture will redraw on top of already drawn thing.

Comment: What do you mean? I just got it working in a little test. `Render texture will redraw on top of already drawn thing`. What behaviour do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think something like this could work? Or is it actually the zooming-code you're wondering about? If so, there are many many answers on this already.

```
OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag == "ZoomArea") {
        // Camera zoom in code
    }
}

OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag == "ZoomArea") {
        // Camera zoom out code
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, how does the UI come in to place? Do you need to render a zooming camera (like @Cổ Chí Tâm suggested) on a UI element?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the zoom on a UI canvas (so with images, panels, buttons, etc.) while using an ortographic camera, you can do it in two different ways.

1) Zooming in and out everything (canvas + all the other rendered objects)

- Use `World Space` render mode in the Canvas component of the canvas and assign to it the ortographic camera.
- Modify the zoom of the camera by changing the `Size` of the Camera component of the camera.

2) Zooming in and out only the canvas

- Use `Screen Space - Camera` render mode in the Canvas component and assign to it the camera.
- Set the canvas Scaler to `Constant Pixel Size` and then modify the `Scale Factor` to zoom in-out the canvas.

This is for general zooming. It's not clear if you want to zoom only a specific portion of the screen.